# Java volatile and cache coherency. Am I missing something?

Tags: java, caching, volatile

In numerous articles, YouTube videos, etc., I have seen Java's `volatile` keyword explained as a problem of cache memory, where declaring a variable `volatile` ensures that reads/writes are forced to main memory, and not cache memory.

It has always been my understanding that in modern CPUs, cache memory implements coherency protocols that guarantee that reads/writes are seen equally by all processors, cores, hardware threads, etc, at all levels of the cache architecture. Am I wrong?

[jls-8.3.1.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1.4) simply states

> A field may be declared `volatile`, in which case the Java Memory Model ensures that all threads see a consistent value for the variable (§17.4).

It says nothing about caching. As long as cache coherency is in effect, `volatile` variables simply need to be written to a memory address, as opposed to being stored locally in a CPU register, for example. There may also be other optimizations that need to be avoided to guarantee the contract of `volatile` variables, and thread visibility.

I am simply amazed at the number of people who imply that CPUs do not implement cache coherency, such that I have been forced to go to StackOverflow because I am doubting my sanity. These people go to a great deal of effort, with diagrams, animated diagrams, etc. to imply that cache memory is not coherent.

jls-8.3.1.4 really is all that needs to be said, but if people are going to explain things in more depth, wouldn't it make more sense to talk about CPU Registers (and other optimizations) than blame CPU Cache Memory?

Comment: There are innumerable bad articles, and we can't argue with all of them. If you have a specific question about some specific assertion made by an article, then by all means, put it in your question and it can be answered. But right now it can't. Right now, it looks like you're venting your frustration with bad articles.

Comment: A lot of articles use outdated information, or are written by people who misunderstood things. The cool thing is that you don't need to understand anything about CPU architectures to write safe multithreaded code in Java, as long as you understand the Java Memory Model. The JLS describes an abstraction that the JVM needs to implement. Different architectures implement it differently. Tomorrow it may be able to do that much more efficient than today. At some point, the hardware capabilities and the JVM spec will diverge too much and a new spec (or language) will be needed.

Comment: I'll add an answer shortly. But modern CPU caches are always coherent; that is the task of the cache coherence protocol. And volatile doesn't force writing to main memory. It is sufficient to write to the coherent cache.

Comment: Also in the pre Java 5 memory model documentation, flushing to memory is mentioned. I guess it was used as an illustration, but it is not how modern processors work. The problem is that a lot of engineers are still using this flawed mental model.

Comment: I think your sanity is fine; your understanding is correct.

Comment: Thanks, everyone... yes Erwin, I was venting a little, but mostly I wanted to verify my sanity before I think about correcting any article by posting in the comments. I have seen almost a dozen articles and videos that claim cache is the problem. Yes pveentjer, it was always my understanding the system does not have to flush to DRAM, it just has to keep the caches coherent.

Answer (score 4):

CPUs are very, very fast. That memory is physically a few centimeters away. Let's say 15 centimeters.

The speed of light is 300,000 kilometers per second, give or take. That's 30,000,000,000,000 centimeters every second. The speed of light in medium is not as fast as in vacuum, but it's close so lets ignore that part. That means sending a single signal from the CPU to the memory, even if the CPU and memory both can *instantly* process it all, is already limiting you to 1,000,000,000 or 1Ghz (You need to cover 30 centimeters to get form the core to the memory and back, so you can do that 1,000,000,000 every second. If you can do it any faster, you're travelling backwards in time. Or some such. You get a nobel prize if you figure out how to manage that one).

Processors are about that fast! We measure core speeds in Ghz these days, as in, in the time it takes **the signal to travel**, the CPU's clock has already ticked. In practice of course that memory controller is not instantaneous either, nor is the CPU pipelining system.

Thus:

> It has always been my understanding that in modern CPUs, cache memory implements coherency protocols that guarantee that reads/writes are seen equally by all processors, cores, hardware threads, etc, at all levels of the cache architecture. Am I wrong?

Yes, you are wrong. QED.

I don't know why you think that or where you read that. You misremember, or you misunderstood what was written, or whatever was written was very very wrong.

In actual fact, an actual update to 'main memory' takes on the order of **a thousand** cycles! A CPU is just sitting there, twiddling its thumbs, doing nothing, in a time window where it could roll through a thousand, on some cores, multiple thousands of instructions, memory is that slow. Molasses level slow.

The fix is not registers, you are missing about 20 years of CPU improvement. There aren't 2 layers (registers, then main memory), no. There are more like 5: Registers, on-die cache in multiple hierarchical levels, and then, eventually, main memory. To make it all very very fast these things are very very close to the core. So close, in fact, that each core has their own, and, **drumroll here** - modern CPUs **cannot** read main memory. At all. They are entirely incapable of it.

Instead what happens is that the CPU sees you write or read to main memory and translates that, as it can't actually do any of that, by figuring out which 'page' of memory that is trying to read/write to (each chunk of e.g. 64k worth of memory is a page; actual page size depends on hardware). The CPU then checks if any of the pages loaded in its on-die cache is that page. If yes, great, and it's all mapped to that. Which does mean that, if 2 cores both have that page loaded, they both have **their own copy**, and obviously anything that one core does to its copy is entirely invisible to the other core.

If the CPU does -not- find this page in its own on-die cache you get what's called a cache miss, and the CPU will then check which of its loaded pages is least used, and will purge this page. Purging is 'free' if the CPU hasn't modified it, but if that page is 'dirty', it will first send a ping to the memory controller followed by blasting the entire sequence of 64k bytes into it (because sending a burst is way, way faster than waiting for the signal to bounce back and forth or to try to figure out which part of that 64k block is dirty), and the memory controller will take care of it. Then, that same CPU pings the controller to blast the correct page to it and overwrites the space that was just purged out. Now the CPU 'retries' the instruction, and this time it does work, as that page IS now in 'memory', in the sense that the part of the CPU that translates the memory location to cachepage+offset now no longer throws a CacheMiss.

And whilst all of that is going on, THOUSANDS of cycles can pass, because it's all very very slow. Cache misses suck.

This explains many things:

- It explains why volatile is slow and synchronized is slower. Dog slow. In general if you want big speed, you want processes that run [A] independent (do not need to share memory between cores, except at the very start and very end perhaps to load in the data needed to operate on, and to send out the result of the complex operation), and [B] fit all memory needs to perform the calculation in 64k or so, depending on CPU cache sizes and how many pages of L1 cache it has.
- It explains why one thread can observe a field having value A and another thread observes the same field having a different value for **DAYS** on end if you're unlucky. If the cores aren't doing all that much and the threads checking the values of those fields does it often enough, that page is never purged, and the 2 cores go on their merry way with their local core value for days. A CPU doesn't sync pages for funsies. It only does this if that page is the 'loser' and gets purged.
- It explains why [Spectre](https://meltdownattack.com) happened.
- It explains why LinkedList is slower than ArrayList even in cases where basic fundamental informatics says it should be faster (big-O notation, analysing computational complexity). Because as long as the arraylist's stuff is limited to a single page you can more or less consider it all virtually instant - it takes about the same order of magnitude to fly through an entire page of on-die cache as it takes for that same CPU to wait around for a single cache miss. And LinkedList is horrible on this front: Every `.add` on it creates a tracker object (the linkedlist has to store the 'next' and 'prev' pointers somewhere!) so for every item in the linked list you have to read 2 objects (the tracker and the actual object), instead of just the one (as the arraylist's array is in contiguous memory, that page is worst-case scenario read into on-die once and remains active for your entire loop), and it's very easy to end up with the tracker object and the actual object being on different pages.
- It explains the Java Memory Model rules: Any line of code may **or may not** observe the effect of any other line of code on the value of any field. Unless you have established a happens-before/happens-after relationship using any of the many rules set out in the JMM to establish these. That's to give the JVM the freedom to, you know, not run literally 1000x slower than neccessary, because guaranteeing consistent reads/writes can only be done by flushing memory on every read, and that is 1000x slower than not doing that.

NB: I have massively oversimplified things. I do not have the skill to fully explain ~20 years of CPU improvements in a mere SO answer. However, it should explain a few things, and it is a marvellous thing to keep in mind as you try to analyse what happens when multiple java threads try to write/read to the same field and you haven't gone out of your way to make very very sure you have an HB/HA relationship between the relevant lines. If you're scared now, good. You shouldn't be attempting to communicate between 2 threads often, or even via fields, unless you really, really know what you are doing. Toss it through a message bus, use designs where the data flow is bounded to the start and end of the entire thread's process (make a job, initialize the job with the right data, toss it in an ExecutorPool queue, set up that you get notified when its done, read out the result, don't ever share anything whatsoever with the actual thread that runs it), or talk to each other via the database.

Comment: The unit of transfer between CPU/cache/memory are cache lines. Which on the X86 are 64 bytes.

Comment: Caches on modern CPUs are always coherent, that is the task of the cache coherence protocol.

Comment: When there is a read miss, the instruction doesn't need to be retried. On the X86 the read is put on a load buffer and eventually enters the line fill buffer where the load waits for the cache line to be returned in the right state. As soon as that happens, the load continues.

Comment: In case of a write, the write is stored in the store buffer and the CPU can continue since the write will happen at some point in the future. Eventually the store end up in the line fill buffer where it needs to wait for the cache line to return in the right state. This automatically invalidates the cache line of that store on all other CPUs. Once that happens, the store can be written to the (coherent) cache.

Comment: There are 2 reasons why volatile is slow. First of all it will limit compiler transformations. But it will also involve barriers to make sure that the volatile load/store are ordered with respect to other load/stores. On the X86 the price is paid on the volatile store; the CPU stops processing loads till the store buffer has been drained. And this can be quite expensive because the cache line of the store and all earlier stores in program order, need to be invalidated on all other CPUs.

Comment: One reasons why CPUs can see incoherent data, even though the CPUs caches are coherent, are compiler transformations. E.g. multiple loads from memory could be optimized into a single load and the result placed in some register.

Comment: It isn't happens-before/happens-after, it is happens-before. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html

Comment: There is no flushing of writes to memory. This is a wrong mental model. Volatile will prevent loads/stores being optimized out, but it will not prevent writing to the cache. On the X86 it is possible to bypass the cache e.g. for I/O DMA. Or when you are processing a high data set, but you access the data only once and you don't want to pollute the cache. But the Java volatile has no such abilities. So a volatile read/write will go through the cache; no flushing involved.

Comment: Thanks, @pveentjer, you have really restored my sanity.

Comment: Thanks, @pveentjer. This should be an answer in itself.